# Playing Batman Arkham City with Xbox controller on OS X

Tags: controllers, macos, batman-arkham-city

I want to play `Batman Arkham City` on my MacBook Pro. Is it possible to play it with Xbox controller?

I'm planning to buy it from the AppStore, not via Steam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So [here's a list of supported controllers](http://support.feralinteractive.com/en/mac-games/bmac/faqs/controllers/) for input in Arkham City on Mac.  Xbox controllers do make an appearance further down the list under **Devices Using Third-Party Drivers**, and it looks like you need something called [Tattiebogle](http://tattiebogle.net/index.php/ProjectRoot/Xbox360Controller/OsxDriver) to use Xbox controllers on Mac OS.

> I have created a USB driver which allows you to use wired XBox 360 Controllers via USB, and wireless XBox 360 Controllers via the Microsoft Wireless Gaming Receiver for Windows, on your OSX machine, including support for the Apple Force Feedback library. The driver is licenced under the GPL.